# Why is ping not waiting for timeout when host is not reachable?

Tags: linux, ping

I am trying to use `ping` to "wait until a host responds, or until timeout".

Neither of the deadline (`-w`) or timeout (`-W`) option seem to help in the case in which the host is not reachable and ping returns with **"Destination Host Unreachable"**:

- using timeout: `ping -W 10` -> runs forever
- using timeout with packet count: `ping -c 1 -W 10` -> exits almost immediately with code 1
- using deadline: `ping -w 10` -> exits almost immediately with code 1
- using deadline with packet count: `ping -w 10 -c 1` -> exits almost immediately with code 1

This all doesn't make sense to me. Specifically, why doesn't `ping -W 10` exit at all?

In the case I'm trying to cover, the host is indeed powered off and I'm getting this from `ping`:

```
From 192.168.7.100 icmp_seq=95 Destination Host Unreachable
```

So my local routing seems to know there is no chance to find the host. But still, why do the deadline/timeout options behave so weirdly?

This is on Raspberry Pi bullseye btw, kernel 5.10.92.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to know more, then use `ping -v`. The verbose output will give
more information.

Here is my output when the destination doesn't exist:

```
$ ping -W 10 -v 192.168.1.99
PING 192.168.1.99 (192.168.1.99) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.10 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.10 icmp_seq=6 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.10 icmp_seq=9 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Basically, without a count or any other method to limit its actions,
ping will work forever, getting on each attempt the error of
"Destination Host Unreachable" again and again.

Count (-c) and deadline (-w) are both a limiting conditions which
cause the ping to terminate when they are triggered.

The `-W` parameter gives the timeout to wait for an answer.
It does not specify to stop if the timeout is exceeded, only the time
to wait for an answer, which in your case never arrives.

Comment: So are you saying that `-W` is only used to wait before sending out the next packet? The manpage description _"The option affects only timeout in absence of any responses"_ makes absolutely no sense to me.
About the limiting factor of `-w` - so why is `ping -w 10` then terminating very quickly? There is no packet limit, and the deadline has also not been reached.

Comment: `-w` is "deadline", meaning how long to ping in seconds, so basically similar to "count" as giving a condition for ping to stop. "-W" is not an ending condition, it applies only to how each single ping is conducted, not to how many pings to do (which by default is infinite).

Answer (score 1):

From my limited understanding:

1. You are sending an ICMP ping to a target host.
2. The gateway in front of the target subnet checks and knows that the host doesn't exist on its network.
3. As soon as one gateway on the route between your client and the host you are trying to ping reports that the host is not reachable, there is no reason to keep searching further.
4. The gateway then replies with an ICMP type 3 code 1 packet, indicating that the host is unreachable.
5. `ping` will exit.

Note that `man ping` says

```
-c count
            Stop after sending count ECHO_REQUEST packets. 
            With deadline option, ping waits for count ECHO_REPLY packets, 
            until the timeout expires.
...
-w deadline
           Specify a timeout, in seconds, before ping exits regardless 
           of how many packets have been sent or received. 
           In this case ping does not stop after count packet are sent, 
           it waits either for deadline expire or until count probes 
           are answered or for some error notification from network.

-W timeout
            Time to wait for a response, in seconds. 
            The option affects only timeout in absence of any responses
...

If ping does not receive any reply packets at all it will exit with code 1. 
If a packet count and deadline are both specified,
and fewer than count packets are received by the time the deadline has arrived, 
it will also exit with code 1. 
On other error it exits with code 2. Otherwise it exits with code 0.
```

The behavior you've described would make sense if "packet" as mentioned in the manpage would be defined as ICMP type 0 packet, which is an echo reply from a host that could successfully be reached. As in your case no valid echo reply has been received, but instead a network error of some kind got reported, `ping` will exit.

[ICMP types](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/qsip/7.3.2?topic=applications-icmp-type-code-ids)

[Further information](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ios-nx-os-software/ios-software-releases-121-mainline/12778-ping-traceroute.pdf)

Comment: I don't get it: _-c count: ... With deadline option, ping waits for count ECHO_REPLY packets, until the timeout expires._ `ECHO_REPLY` clearly means ICMP packet type 0, and I am getting count=0 of those. Then why is `ping -w 10 -c 1` terminating? The deadline option is given. count is zero. timeout has not expired.

Edit: I joust found the crucial part: _-w deadline: ... it waits either for deadline expire or until count probes are answered **or for some error notification from network**_

Comment: Yes, but although the host is currently unreachable, it may become reachable within the deadline. For example, `wol` is used to power on a host. Then, ping with both a count and deadline would be used to wait for the host to establish a network connection. For example, `wol aa:aa:aa:bb:bb:bb && ping -c 3 -w 120 10.0.0.99`